# Memo In Crystal Report Displaying Only 260 Characters

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008, crystal-reports-xi, crystal-reports-2010

I have Crystal Report version 11.5, in that using Database Fieds I dragged and dropped the field which is showing as Memo in the database field section, in the detail section, but it is still displaying 260 characters, when it has more than that to display data. I googled and tried suggested settings, but till no use.

Tried by unselecting two Distance options in the Report Options, but still not working.

Any suggestion?

Comment: You're sure these fields have more than 260 characters in the database? Have you tried running the query outside of CR to see if those fields contain the expected data?

Comment: yes the problem must be from database, make sure to keep the nvarchar(MAX) or something like that